# Cannot insert std::unique_ptr with custom deleter with std::move

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, stdmap, stdmove

I use a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter as a value of a `std::map` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

void deleter(int* p){
    std::cout<<"Deleting..."<<std::endl;
    delete p;
}

int main()
{   
    std::map<char, std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)>> a;
    std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> p{new int{3}, deleter}; 
    a['k'] = std::move(p);
}
```

When inserting a value, I use `std::move`, but it will not compile.

What am I doing wrong?

You see the errors following link.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/fKL4QDkUTDsj4gDc

Comment: Change the last line to `a.emplace('k', std::move(p));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a['k']` will default construct the value type of the map if the key does not exist.  Since your `unique_ptr` uses a custom deleter, it is not default constructable.  You will have to use either [`map::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) or [`map::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) to add the `unique_ptr` to the map.  If you want to know if the element exists or not before you do so, you can use either [`map::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) or [`map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

If you can use C++17, you can use [`map::try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) instead, which will only add the object if the key does not exist, saving you a lookup.

Comment: If you read the compiler's error messages more carefully, the default constructor issue is actually pointed out to you: "*required from `...::operator[](...)` ... error: no matching function for call to **`std::unique_ptr<int, void (*)(int*)>::unique_ptr()`***"

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in the default construction of the map entry before the assignment!

Sorry no time to work up the answer, but generally I would use insert instead?